# RotateAround an object with using Quaternion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have a great question for code masters. Think about you have only a calculated rotation value to rotate the transform. But you have to rotate around with its child pivot position. How do you solve this problem?

Thank you for your time :)

[image: RotateAround an object with using Quaternion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the code.
Here is the solution.

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? ;)

Unity has [`Transform.RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) and for the input you could simply use [`Quaternion.ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html) like e.g.

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static void RotateAround(this Transform transform, Transform pivot, Quaternion rotation)
    {  
        RotateAround (transform, pivot.transform.position, rotation);
    } 

    public static void RotateAround(this Transform transform, Vector3 pivotPoint, Quaternion rotation)
    {   
        rotation.ToAngleAxis(out var angle, out var axis);

        transform.RotateAround(pivotPoint, axis, angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @derHugo, probably this can solve the problem too but I've already found the solution and posted it on Jun 2.

Comment: @user1485689 you found **a** solution, yes. If it is the best solution is questionable. I don't say that mine is significantly more efficient either ;) StackOverflow is not for having one answer but for having multiple ones so other users with the same question can easily find solutions and take the one that is most helpful for them ;)

Comment: Of course, you are absolutely right. Thank you for your time. :)